# Manipulating the slider - the circle disappears

Tags: javascript, browser, slider

Manipulating the slider until the end, the circle that represents the star disappears or does a different motion. See: jsfiddle.net/NxNXJ/13 Unlike this: astro.unl.edu/naap/hr/animations/hrExplorer.html

Can you help me?? Thanks

Comment: Changing this line: var widthOfSun = 130; instead of var widthOfSun = 150;
and changing the sun's size to 130px istead of 150px. Thus the browser chrome and opera run as this link: http://astro.unl.edu/naap/hr/animations/hrExplorer.html ....only in Firefox the problem continues.

Comment: Hi Waleria, I noticed in your previous two answers that when a user answered your question, you didn't mark their post as your selected answer, which is standard etiquette for SO. If a post solves your problem, click the white checkmark next to the post.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here on SO. I'm sorry it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you supply a big luminosity, You're rendering a circle which is millions of pixels tall. The broswer might not render it because it's so big.
However, you are really only interested in a small slice of that big circle - namely, the bit that fits in your tiny window.
At some point, it doesn't make sense to increase the size of the circle, since you can't observe a change in the curvature of the circle - it just looks like a straight vertical line.

This apparent verticality occurs around when x^2 + y^2 = R^2, where R is the radius of the star, Y is half the height of your window, and x is R-1. Solve for R in terms of Y, and you get

```
function maximumNecessaryRadius(windowHeight){
    y = windowHeight / 2;
    maxRadius = (y*y - 1)/2;
    return Math.round(maxRadius);
}
```

When resizing the star, check to make sure that its radius doesn't exceed the maximum necessary radius. Rendering it any larger than that is overkill.

[Example Implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/NxNXJ/16/)